# Converting a list of words into a list of the frequency in which those words appear

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am doing extensive work with a variety of word lists.

Please consider the following question that I have:

```
docText={"settlement", "new", "beginnings", "wildwood", "settlement", "book",
"excerpt", "agnes", "leffler", "perry", "my", "mother", "junetta", 
"hally", "leffler", "brought", "my", "brother", "frank", "and", "me", 
"to", "edmonton", "from", "monmouth", "illinois", "mrs", "matilda", 
"groff", "accompanied", "us", "her", "husband", "joseph", "groff", 
"my", "father", "george", "leffler", "and", "my", "uncle", "andrew", 
"henderson", "were", "already", "in", "edmonton", "they", "came", 
"in", "1910", "we", "arrived", "july", "1", "1911", "the", "sun", 
"was", "shining", "when", "we", "arrived", "however", "it", "had", 
"been", "raining", "for", "days", "and", "it", "was", "very", 
"muddy", "especially", "around", "the", "cn", "train"}

searchWords={"the","for","my","and","me","and","we"}
```

Each of these lists are much longer (say 250 words in the `searchWords` list and `docText` being about 12,000 words).

Right now, I have the ability to figure out frequency of a given word by doing something like:

```
docFrequency=Sort[Tally[docText],#1[[2]]>#2[[2]]&];    
Flatten[Cases[docFrequency,{"settlement",_}]][[2]]
```

But where I am getting hung up is on my quest to generate specific lists. Specifically, the issue of converting a list of words into a list of the frequency in which those words appear. I've tried to do this with `Do` loops but have hit a wall.

I want to go through `docText` with `searchWords` and replace each element of docText with the sheer frequency of its appearance. I.e. since "settlement" appears twice, it would be replaced by 2 in the list, whereas since "my" appears 3 times, it would become 3. The list would then be something like 2,1,1,1,2, and so forth.

I suspect the answer lies somewhere in `If[]` and `Map[]`?

This all sounds weird, but I am trying to pre-process a bunch of information for term frequency information…

---

**Addition for Clarity (I hope):**

Here is a better example.

```
searchWords={"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "A", "about", 
"above", "across", "after", "again", "against", "all", "almost", 
"alone", "along", "already", "also", "although", "always", "among", 
"an", "and", "another", "any", "anyone", "anything", "anywhere", 
"are", "around", "as", "at", "b", "B", "back", "be", "became", 
"because", "become", "becomes", "been", "before", "behind", "being", 
"between", "both", "but", "by", "c", "C", "can", "cannot", "could", 
"d", "D", "do", "done", "down", "during", "e", "E", "each", "either", 
"enough", "even", "ever", "every", "everyone", "everything", 
"everywhere", "f", "F", "few", "find", "first", "for", "four", 
"from", "full", "further", "g", "G", "get", "give", "go", "h", "H", 
"had", "has", "have", "he", "her", "here", "herself", "him", 
"himself", "his", "how", "however", "i", "I", "if", "in", "interest", 
"into", "is", "it", "its", "itself", "j", "J", "k", "K", "keep", "l", 
"L", "last", "least", "less", "m", "M", "made", "many", "may", "me", 
"might", "more", "most", "mostly", "much", "must", "my", "myself", 
"n", "N", "never", "next", "no", "nobody", "noone", "not", "nothing", 
"now", "nowhere", "o", "O", "of", "off", "often", "on", "once", 
"one", "only", "or", "other", "others", "our", "out", "over", "p", 
"P", "part", "per", "perhaps", "put", "q", "Q", "r", "R", "rather", 
"s", "S", "same", "see", "seem", "seemed", "seeming", "seems", 
"several", "she", "should", "show", "side", "since", "so", "some", 
"someone", "something", "somewhere", "still", "such", "t", "T", 
"take", "than", "that", "the", "their", "them", "then", "there", 
"therefore", "these", "they", "this", "those", "though", "three", 
"through", "thus", "to", "together", "too", "toward", "two", "u", 
"U", "under", "until", "up", "upon", "us", "v", "V", "very", "w", 
"W", "was", "we", "well", "were", "what", "when", "where", "whether", 
"which", "while", "who", "whole", "whose", "why", "will", "with", 
"within", "without", "would", "x", "X", "y", "Y", "yet", "you", 
"your", "yours", "z", "Z"}
```

These are the automatically generated stopwords from `WordData[]`. So I want to compare these words against docText. Since "settlement" is NOT part of `searchWords`, then it would appear as 0. But since "my" is part of `searchWords`, it would pop up as the count (so I could tell how many times the given word appears).

I really do thank you for your help - I'm looking forward to taking some formal courses soon as I'm bumping up against the edge of my ability to really explain what I want to do!

Comment: Do you need to *only* handle those words that appear in `searchWords`?  What happens with the rest in `docWords`?

Comment: @Szabolcs If they don't appear, they should appear as a 0. In a previous program, I used an `If` to convert it to 0 because I would get the null issue.

Comment: I still don't understand completely. Can you explain the role of `searchWords`?

Comment: @Szabolcs Certainly - let me take a second to think, and I'll edit the question above. My apologies for the vagueness...

Comment: Hey, Ian, why didn't you post this over on [mathematica.se](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)? :)

Comment: @rcollyer I'm still a bit unsure of the relationship btw the two sites. Even specifically programming-oriented questions should be asked there? I'm happy to completely migrate there, though, as it's a great site!

Comment: I don't understand this part: `Sort[Tally[docText],#1[[2]]#2[[2]]&];`.  Do you mean `Sort[Tally[docText],#1[[2]] > #2[[2]]&];` ?

Comment: Since you asked it here, it needs to stay here. But, anything having to do with how to do something in Mathematica is on topic.

Comment: @TomD Had it in there wrong - yes, that's the code that sorts it correctly.

Comment: @rcollyer Force of habit. I feel like a dummy now: I'll ask my next Qs over there!

Comment: It's more rep on SO, so not a total loss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can replace everything that doesn't appear in `searchWords` by 0 in `docText` as follows:

```
preprocessedDocText = 
   Replace[docText, 
     Dispatch@Append[Thread[searchWords -> searchWords], _ -> 0], {1}]
```

The we can replace the remaining words by their frequency:

```
replaceTable = Dispatch[Rule @@@ Tally[docText]];

preprocessedDocText /. replaceTable
```

`Dispatch` preprocesses a list of rules (`->`) and speeds up replacement significantly in subsequent uses.

I have not benchmarked this on large data, but `Dispatch` should provide a good speedup.

Comment: I see the confusion, this is my fault.. please give me a minute or two.

Comment: This is great and very clean code, BTW. Thanks for explaining what it does!

Comment: This is fantastic. It seems extremely quick! In a few minutes, I will try it on my largest corpus to time it out!

Answer (score 4):

@Szabolcs gave a fine solution, and I'd probably go the same route myself. Here is a slightly different solution, just for fun:

```
ClearAll[getFreqs];
getFreqs[docText_, searchWords_] :=
  Module[{dwords, dfreqs, inSearchWords, lset},
    SetAttributes[{lset, inSearchWords}, Listable];
    lset[args__] := Set[args];
    {dwords, dfreqs} = Transpose@Tally[docText];
    lset[inSearchWords[searchWords], True];
    inSearchWords[_] = False;
    dfreqs*Boole[inSearchWords[dwords]]]
```

This shows how `Listable` attribute may be used to replace loops and even `Map`-ping. We have:

```
In[120]:= getFreqs[docText,searchWords]
Out[120]= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,
1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,2,0,2,0,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0}
```

Answer (score 2):

I set out to solve this in a different way from Szabolcs but I ended up with something rather similar.

Nevertheless, I think it is cleaner.  On some data it is faster, on others slower.

```
docText /. 
  Dispatch[FilterRules[Rule @@@ Tally@docText, searchWords] ~Join~ {_String -> 0}]
```